# Why was this question deleted when answers had upvotes?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

I'm a little confused as to why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810069/which-complexity-is-less-on-or-on-logn/25810161#25810161) was deleted after receiving so many upvotes in its answers.

I understand it had been closed (can't remember the specific reason now), but I stumbled across it's deletion today, and am slightly confused as to why?

the answers had been upvoted (if I remember correctly, I had a number of upvotes) - as did others.

---

It was my understanding that closed questions were to 'stay' and be used as 'signposts'? Or am I misunderstanding how the deletion process works?

---

**Please note**, i'm not disagreeing with the vote, more just wanting to understand how to process worked.

Comment: 3 10K users decided to delete it. And it's not actually a loss, as it wasn't a good sign-posts, and there are more than enough still standing.

Comment: Moderator deletes post, community disagrees. Moderator undeletes post, Meta Police disagrees. Can't win.

Comment: @BoltClock: hey, [we cheer you on often enough](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock?tab=answers&sort=votes). No whining when wrong! :-P

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: But [poor ol' George doesn't get as much love](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=6) as I do :(

Comment: @BoltClock: Cheater, that's the last page by votes ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock: Get out the pitchforks! Call for a new election! Time to replace the failing ruling class!

Comment: @Deduplicator: that's the point, though; compare that to Bolt's lowest-voted posts. Boltclock just knows when to keep schtum. :-P

Comment: I Think I shouldn't have opened this can of worms. I was merely trying to understand the logic, not start a war. Sorry!

Comment: @jbutler483: This comment thread is just in good fun, don't worry. Can't exactly say the same for the answers however...

Comment: @BoltClock: Still, there's something happening here i didn't expect.

Comment: Yeah, it's par for the course for meta. Don't sweat it.

Comment: ok. I trust I'll look back and everyone will be dancing together. I'm gonna go here and answer some questions, and see the outcome later. G'luck! :)

Comment: Quick, someone whip up an image of George dancing with a unicorn and a ninja doll.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't even know what that means.

Answer (score 7):

It was deleted by community vote; 3 members of the community voted to delete it. I agree with the vote.

The question is *greatly underspecified* and there already is a [fantastic post on Big O notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o). The *question* then wasn't adding anything to the body of knowledge (it wasn't particularly findable via Google, one of the reasons to keep duplicates around).

Your answer wasn't really anything of lasting value either; you quoted a graph from an external source. If you feel you can *expand* on that answer to cover more information, by all means post it as an additional answer to the canonical post. I don't think that post needs anything else however.

In the meantime, a moderator has undeleted the post again. I'm not sure I'd have done the same however.

Comment: I understand that it may not have been the 'best' of questions, but I thought the 'upvotes' explained how it was at least *useful* to them. Please note, i'm not disagreeing with the vote, more just wanting to understand how to process worked.

Comment: @jbutler483: Sometimes initial popularity and visibility can inflate vote counts. You got 9 of the 10 votes on the day it was posted, and one additional vote 3 weeks ago. That, to me, means the post hasn't had much attention after it was posted.

Comment: @jbutler483 Upvotes to answers of NEW questions don't mean anyone found it useful, because they don't come from people who found the question from a Google search. They came from people looking at the front page, and are more like Facebook "like".

Comment: Personally, I don't like to see the deletion of questions that have good answers. While the question it was closed as a duplicate of was a far better one, and had some even better answers, I don't know that it helps to delete this question and its answers. I'm becoming concerned with some of the deletions I've been seeing lately of duplicate questions, many of which had good answers.

Comment: @BradLarson: I agree on the *good answers* part. I think we disagree on there being good answers *here*.

Comment: @BradLarson I can't see how anyone would be better off reading this question's answers than the canonical question's answers, nor do I see these answers as adding value on top of the canonical question's answers.  If it's not adding any value, and it at risk of drawing attention away from much better content, it is better for the site to just delete it.