# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Recently I saw that a [question I had answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042494/is-it-necessary-to-close-an-inputstreamreader-in-a-bufferedreader/32042524#32042524) had been deleted.

#### Images for users under 10k:

[image]

[image]

I'm wondering why this was. Both the question and my answer (which was accepted) had upvotes.

[This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285758/why-was-this-question-deleted-when-answers-had-upvotes) suggests it could be because there are already many questions asking the same/similar things (see links at bottom) and this answer adds nothing, but it seems to me that the duplicate association was enough, and does not meet the [criteria outlined here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled):

> **Should duplicates be deleted?**
>
> In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.
>
> Duplicates that are word-for-word copies or that are so poorly written that they are not useful may be deleted by users with sufficient privilege.

Basically, what was the motivation/thought process behind this deletion and does the community feel this was the right choice?

**Edit:**

It seems the course of action in cases such as these is disagreed upon by high-rep users, as can be seen here: [Why was this question deleted when answers had upvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285758/why-was-this-question-deleted-when-answers-had-upvotes#comment153602_285759). (Though we could also argue about whether my answer constitutes "good" in this situation.)

---

**On a slightly different note:**
Why haven't all the questions in this vein been marked as duplicates?

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263926/closing-inputstreams-in-java)
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362980/when-i-close-a-bufferedinputstream-is-the-underlying-inputstream-also-closed?lq=1)
- [This question (maybe not an exact duplicate, but quite similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388602/do-i-need-to-close-both-filereader-and-bufferedreader)

All seem like they should have been marked as duplicates of each other in some way, but have escaped the dupe treatment somehow.

Comment: What about this duplicate makes it easier to find than all of the other information on the internet about this issue?  What's going to allow someone to find this question when they wouldn't be able to find that information from any of the other places that it's answered?

Comment: I'm not a java expert, but just because something has upvotes doesn't mean it shouldn't be deleted. Ask yourself what *new value* does this question/answer adds to the already existing one. If you find some then it would be worth to keep it.

Comment: If you see other questions that are duplicates, flag them for closure, rather than complaining about the fact that others haven't noticed it.

Comment: @Servy I have done so, just bringing them up as part of this whole discussion as I found it relevant.

Comment: @River The fact that there are so many duplicates of this extremely common problem (that's trivially resolved by reading the documentation about the class the question is asking about) that many of the duplicates aren't being closed, as there's just too many to catch them all, only further solidifies that they aren't worth keeping around.

Comment: @Rizier123 fair point, I'm just saying it indicates some level of value (really the only indicator SO has). Whether it is accurate or not is up for debate.

Comment: @River The fact that there are tons and tons of duplicates of this exact problem doesn't make those duplicates more valuable.  It means that they're actively harmful to the community.

Comment: @Servy is three over 7 years really "too many to catch them all?". Or are you just saying these are the few that have slipped through? And are you also saying some of the other questions I mentioned should also be removed?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why was my duplicate question deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318594)?

Comment: @River There are hundreds of thousands of questions that merit closure that aren't closed, because there aren't enough people voting to close close-worthy questions.  You seem to have found 3 of them.

Comment: @Servy and is it somehow bad to bring them up so they get closed...?

Comment: @River We  it's enough to just flag them for closure.  I'm just saying that bringing them up is providing evidence to support the deletion of the post; bringing them up is fine, if that's what you're trying to show with it.

Comment: I think with the comments we came to the point, that if a post is a duplicate, but adds *new value* to the already existing ones, then it's worth to keep them. So maybe a java expert(s) can say if it adds new value or not. If it doesn't I think we all can understand why it was deleted.

Comment: related: [Thwart publishing duplicate and low quality questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions)

Comment: @Servy to clarify, I'm not trying to get my post undeleted. I'm trying to understand why it was deleted/if it was the right call, and if any of those similar posts should merely be made duplicates or deleted as well (obviously not all of them).

Comment: @George Stocker (I know that maybe you can't see this ping but lets hope), I'm just wondering why did you undelete it? for meta reasons (you like us to see it and vote), or do you believe it has value? (Note: I'm only curious about the reason) I don't have 10K so can just look and learn.

Comment: The question your answer was on is a duplicate; it should have been closed BEFORE being answered. Other questions that are duplicates should be considered for closure as well. Please, flag them as duplicates when you find them. Many (many!) questions escape the dupe treatment, as you put it, simply because there are too few users willing to take the step.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Undeleted for a few reasons: 1) It's an extremely well written question (and answer) that is bound to hit search queries; in the case of duplicates, that's a good thing.  It's got a much better title than the question it was closed as a duplicate of; for one. 2) Undeleted so non 10Kers can see the question and help fuel the debate. It's hard to debate something you can't see.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The question got virtually no views over the course of most of a year before being deleted.  There's no need for any of us to make a judgement call about whether or not we think that this question is likely to be found more easily than other sources.  We have very compelling observational evidence that it doesn't.  if it *was* more discoverable than other sources, it would have attracted more than just a handful of views in that time.  So we don't *think* that this isn't a useful window, we **know** that it isn't.

Comment: @Mogsdad I flagged it as a duplicate a few days ago (because that's when I realized it was thanks to Tunaki). I answered it 7+ months ago, when I didn't realize there were many duplicates. I realize duplicate answers should ideally be closed as such rather than answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was deleted because it adds nothing of value.  There is nothing that that question is contributing to anyone that isn't already being provided by the many other duplicates of that problem.  That question isn't adding new information, it's not easier to find, nor is it referenced elsewhere.  It attracted ~100 views in the *two-thirds of* an entire year before it was deleted.  That's very clear evidence that it is not providing a window into the canonical duplicate, nor containing information worth referencing directly.

This is a *textbook* case of a question that merits deletion.

Comment: I think worth to note is also, that only because a question/answer has upvotes doesn't necessarily mean it is *more* worth to keep it.

Comment: @Rizier123 true, but that is *usually* the case or at least what upvotes are designed to represent. You are right that they may not always reflect that.

Comment: @River Over the course of the first 8 months the question attracted all of **one** upvote, and the answer attracted two.  Meanwhilte *five* people voted to close the question, and three more voted to delete it.  Clearly many more of the readers felt that the content here wasn't valuable than though it was valuable.

Comment: @Servy *sigh* I was just saying upvotes usually correlate to quality so they should at least be mentioned, even if they don't necessarily apply in this case. (Also it was closed by a *single* user who was also one of the 3 who voted to delete it)

Comment: @River When there's only one vote on the post, you can't really correlate it to anything meaningful; it's just one vote.  Votes, *in the aggregate*, can correlate to quality.

Comment: Servy, you've described my thoughts on the deletion reason exactly. In cases where a duplicate has very high views, it's more clearly useful as a marker to the target or canonical question. This is hard to judge on a new question, but once months or a year later it's clear - as it was here.

Comment: @Mogsdad I'm not sure the case is so clear, [others in the community seem to have had different opinions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285758/why-was-this-question-deleted-when-answers-had-upvotes#comment153602_285759) (though maybe this simply turns this into a discussion of whether my and the other answer on this dupe are considered "good")

Comment: @River So you're freely admitting that  your answer isn't adding any value, and that nothing would be lost by it being deleted, but you don't think it should be deleted anyway?  Why do you think that we should be rewarding, and maintaining, content that isn't useful to anyone?  Also, that's just a passing, incomplete, thought posted by one person in a comment.  That doesn't make it official policy, or community consensus.

Comment: @Servy where do I "freely admit" that my answer isn't adding value? I feel it is a good answer, and while the question itself may not be extremely visible, isn't it better to leave it up on the chance that it will help someone find a solution? What harm does it do undeleted? (And wouldn't downvotes be a more appropriate method to prevent rewarding the poster, rather than deletion?)

Comment: @River I'm the one that closed the question and initially voted to delete. This answer is exactly why I did so. I actually find it harmful to keep because it adds no new information and is therefore diluting the information around. There is nothing wrong with your answer, it just adds no new information. I'll note that this is already present directly in the Javadoc.

Comment: @River Well, I've asked you why you feel that it adds value, and you've provided nothing.  I've provided lots of different types of evidence that it's *not* providing value, and you've responded by linking to a comment saying that we should consider not deleting posts, even when they're adding nothing of value.  That seems like a pretty clear concession to me that the post isn't adding any value.  If you think that it is, then you should probably support that position.

Comment: @Servy I feel you're misrepresenting the position taken in that comment... You also seem to be confusing the question and my answer to it. I'm saying the question may not be particularly visible, and so not add *much* value, but this is far from *no* or *negative* value, as someone stumbling across the post would still find value in it. Deleting it robs the post of potential to help others, whereas, in my opinion, leaving it up as a duplicate does no harm.

Comment: @Tunaki I can understand your position, however I fail to see how dilution is harmful if it 1) provides the solution and 2) links to the canonical question.

Comment: @River So you think that without this post there are going to be people that wouldn't be able to find a solution to this problem?  Sorry, but I just can't see that, and the evidence bears that out.  You and I don't need to guess whether or not your answer would help people find the solution.  We could clearly see that it *didn't* help people find the solution over the *lengthy* time in which it was undeleted.

Comment: @River I don't want to stretch this discussion longer, but a few things I want to add, where you/ we all have to differentiate. 1) It can be good to have multiple questions worded differently, which are duplicates pointing to a canonical. 2) A canonical can have multiple very valuable answers. 3) There is a point where more duplicate questions pointing to a canonical don't add any new value to it and can even make it harder to find the answers. 4) New valuable answers to duplicate questions are best posted on the canonical most valuable question and not on side duplicate questions.

Comment: @River So if I went to every single post that you've ever answered, and copy-pasted the content of your answer into a new answer, I would be being helpful?  What if thousands of people did the same thing on every post you posted?

Comment: @River Also to summarize what I think we all gained here already: We all understand that the Q&A was deleted, because it doesn't add any new value to the existing duplicates (If you/we now agree with this or not). And I also think that this would be the answer to your meta question here. Leaving open to discussing if it should be deleted or not.

Comment: @Rizier123 good point. I disagree with some of the points made by Servy but as evidenced by Tunaki, his answer does answer *why* my post was deleted. I suppose I lost sight of that as accepting an answer feels much like conceding to the answer's argument. Thanks for nudging me into noticing the difference.

Comment: @Servy that's not even close to the case being discussed here...

Comment: @River I suppose that's true.  In your case there's dramatically less information in your answer than in the other sources available, so it's not just duplication of content, it's providing a lower quality copy.

Comment: @Servy I think we've already addressed all the points worth talking over, and as, in my view, your comments seem to have progressed from vaguely patronizing to borderline rude, I think we should end the discussion here.

Comment: @River I'm happy that we had a good question and good discussion around it :) For the end: Since the Q&A was deleted and undeleted by a mod we just leave it open if it is worth to keep. If other users come by and feel that it doesn't add anything and delete it then it may be so. But at least we all know why. If you feel that your answer adds new useful content to the already existing ones, I would recommend you to delete the existing one and post your answer on the canonical. With this it will be less likely to be deleted and your answer will be more visible. And now we can all get our teas.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yeah, I misread the date the first time, but even at 2/3 of a year the point stands.  100 views over that time is still basically nothing.