# A question got deleted which deleted my answer, and I lost reputation

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Yesterday I answered a question, got an acceptance check-mark, 4 upvotes, and a total of 55 reputation points.

I woke up this morning, and the question got deleted which also deleted my answer, and I lost those 55 reputation points. This is very annoying.

When I try to delete a post that someone else answered, the system says that I can't delete it, and I understand why. But this post got deleted by 3 people, and here is the thing - they deleted it because:

> Closed. This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers.

But when I try to improve the question, I get this message:

> This post is deleted and cannot be edited.

Why? I don't get it! This question doesn't look so terrible. I don't understand why it got deleted with no option to fix it. If you can see the post somehow, this is it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836507/how-to-put-comma-between-each-digit-of-a-number/68836546#68836546

Comment: Consider answering questions that are better than "not so terrible".

Comment: At best, it's a duplicate. Don't you think the question about using `join` hasn't been asked already? Many, many times? At worst it's a (poor) work order. Not a post to spill tears about. Look for more interesting questions to answer.

Comment: *I don't understand why it got deleted with no option to fix it*: The author of the question can still edit it, and also users with enough rep can. You cannot suggest edits (which have to be reviewed).

Comment: *"they deleted it because:"* - well no, that's a close reason. Deletion is a separate path dictated by a separate voting round not directly tied to closure. I'm pretty sure this was deleted because it is the hundredth duplicate which is not ever going to be useful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The linked question was apparently sitting in a curation borderline. It was one of the form *"I have this code which does X but I want it to do Y"*, with no attempt towards fulfilling Y (other than the code which already did X), and no concrete question about what was stopping the OP from doing Y. Many of the comments found in that question were either hinting towards a solution or warning the author that they should have shown more effort or continued learning the basics of the programming language so as to know what constructs to employ.

Now, zero effort isn't a reason to close a question, but the curators involved in the closure may have had the opinion that the question was too vague, and that it wasn't useful in the long term. I have no intention to say whether the closure was appropriate or not here, as it sits in a tricky borderline. On the one hand, it may well be answerable if the requirements are sufficiently clear. On the other hand, the question's usefulness as a plain problem dump was contested, likely already answered by existing questions, and reopening a question just to mark is as a duplicate is inefficient and does not make sense for a question which was likely to be deleted anyway (since duplicate closure also opens the path towards deletion by vote).

---

Ultimately, this is a situation where you should **choose better questions to answer**. A question which poses itself as little more than an assignment dump is in good chance of being closed and deleted. Picking better questions to answer reduces the chance of losing reputation if they are deleted.

See also:

- [Why was this question deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319744)