# Why was a duplicate question deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57790636/round-numbers-to-closest-10s-in-angular/57790764#57790764) and realized that it was deleted. The question was closed as a duplicate and deleted within 5 days of being asked.

What is the deletion criteria for duplicates?

I feel like I should have been notified that a question I answered was deleted.

Picture of post for <10k users: 
[image]

Comment: We shouldn't be answering duplicates to begin with. How many times do the same answers need to be re-iterated? Better spend your time on more worthwhile questions.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I think that what you are mentionning as worthwile questions is ambiguous. I don't consider the question myself as a duplicate one otherwise I would not have answered it.

Comment: You should not be punished for the question being a duplicate. Deleting questions that are duplicates is of marginal utility at best since we don’t know what keywords searchers will use, and the upvotes ensuring the question doesn’t remain in the “unanswered” algorithm. In effect, deleting the question hurts us more than it helps us.

Comment: How so? What's different about this specific "how do I round to the nearest 10's"?

Comment: Second, closing that question as a duplicate is incorrect as it’s talking about how to implement a Pipe to round, which is quite different than vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, the OP asked about the angular way of solving the problem @StoryTeller. Angular is not JavaScript

Comment: And there is no Angular dupe? I'm no subject matter expert, but this sounds unlikely to me.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027749/angular-2-how-round-calculated-number. I'm also no angular export, but it took me 5 seconds to google that dupe. I think it can be expected that an answerer searches a bit before answering. Nevertheless, I see no real benefit in deleting that question.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @bdl. Now can we keep from deleting this one? Signposts are no good if we delete them.

Comment: There are plenty "create pipe module" questions. And "round number" questions. Unless we need a question for "create pipe module round 10", "create pipe module round to integer", "create pipe module two decimals", etc, etc, etc. There gets to a point where an excess of duplicates no longer makes finding things easier.  Too many signposts are not a good signalling strategy, IMO. The trusted users who voted to delete probably thought that way.

Comment: @bdl I used to think that way too. I now realize that doesn’t help the site; but it took me a really long time to get there.

Comment: Over the last month I got the feeling that way too many questions get deleted by votes at the moment. Tons of posts that would be deleted by roomba anyway, and also a lot that aren't. Maybe we need a big public discussion on when delete votes should be used.

Comment: There should not be a double standard. See these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003551/how-do-i-filter-an-array-with-typescript-in-angular-2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes. They practically use the same method `filter` and one question is not marked as the duplicate of the other

Comment: @yivi I may agree with you if the source duplicate they originally picked would have answered the question. It wouldn’t have. It would have left a gaping hole the OP would have to ask another question about to fill in because angular insists on being... unique.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, making a pipe out of that function is as easy as putting the vanilla JS function in a pipe shell

Comment: This is what you think @Vega, but the OP did not figure it out. Unless you mean that the OP is stupid by asking the question and so are all others asking a question when they could go on the official website to find the answer by themselves

Comment: @GeorgeStocker *"get there"* and *"realize"* are not appropriate ways to communicate what is your opinion.

Comment: @edkeveked That's why we help him by linking a duplicate. SO is not a tutorial site. I didn't insinuate anything about the OP

Comment: @Vega: Duplicates are perfect **when they fit the question**. This one didn't. And deleting a question with a wrong duplicate doesn't help at all.

Comment: The tricky part is that the question secretly asks two questions; having both questions answered by one dupe closure is not going to cut it. Question 1: how to round specifically to the given specifications using Javascript; the original dupe link answers that part. Question 2: how do you do that in an Angular pipe - the second dupe suggestion answers that part.

Comment: @BDL, that's your opinion that it was the wrong dupe. I considered it the right one. The OP was non responsive, so I considered it accepted. The question didn't have any useful value for SO, it had to go

Comment: @Gimby - Perfect chance to edit the duplicate list and add both links.

Comment: Now the question even has a reopen vote. Maybe because the dupe simply uses `floor` and does not round to the nearest multiple of ten?

Comment: The actual dupe is not the correct one. Please leave the Angular "experts" handle

Comment: I fail to see how it's not correct, it explains how to use pipes, OP can use their own initiative to look up how to round to nearest 10, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022488/javascript-using-round-to-the-nearest-10/11022517) for example, and use that instead of the `return Math.floor(input);` in the posted dupe. We don't need to hold peoples hands, they need to figure stuff out on their own given the right prompts, which they were given

Comment: @NickA, for using pipes, there are tons of sources (SO and not SO). For using the JS function to round, tons also. The question is in fact "Too broad", lacking efforts. I hammered it as dupe to help the OP

Comment: @Yivi not a duplicate of that as the question is neither bad (the upvotes for the question and answer reflect that) and deleting duplicates is different than non duplicates.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I believe this question is a duplicate and the linked question is bad.

Comment: @StoryTeller that would be my choice if no good answer was given. But the provided singular answer covers both questions admirably... Having two individual dupe links which need to be combined to get to the total solution does not strike me as improving the question at this point.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was working out at the time so the best I could do were comments; I've since posted an answer explaining why our moderation guidelines are what they are.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker '*\(the upvotes for the question and answer reflect that)*' - Though they can be used as a indicator for a good questions, the advice is always given to not use them as an indicator.

Comment: @Script47 The advice from whom? Random Meta people? Moderators? CMs?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker a mod.

Comment: @Script47 Do you have a link to the context of this advice?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker not at the top of my head. But there a tons of examples of questions which get hundreds of up-votes but get closed because they are "bad" questions (see book requests or overly broad popular topics).

Comment: @Script47 closed is different than deleted; and for each category of closure, the deletion rules are different. One universal constant is that [we do not delete good content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/16587).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker of course, but if you look back,  I wasn't talking about deletion. Merely your statement that votes reflect the quality of a question.

Answer (score -9):

Our [criteria for human deletion are as follows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/16587) (emphasis added):

> For questions, a post that no longer adds anything to the site should be deleted. Basically, this includes most closed questions that cannot be improved and reopened. However, **it may be beneficial to keep duplicates to aid future users in finding the canonical question, as different people may use different wordings that cause the canonical question to not show up in search**.
>
> For answers, any post that is not an answer (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice should be downvoted, not deleted.
>
> These are general guidelines; some communities in the network may uphold more specific reasons to delete posts or not. For example, on Puzzling.SE, answers to a puzzle without explanation are subject to deletion, and some technical sites will delete answers which are not only wrong but also harmful when tried.

For Stack Overflow specifically, [our guidelines are this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284467/should-number-of-lines-from-xcode-project-really-be-deleted-should-it-be-merg):

> In general, duplicates should be merged instead of deleted.
>
> The Merge path should be:
>
> The question with the greatest views, votes, and 'better' answers (a wholly subjective criterion, but normally something with code is better than something without, and something with just a link and a description is worse than anything else) becomes the canonical question.
>
> The other questions should be flagged for merging into that canonical question.
>
> It's OK if some of the questions are not merged -- there may be times when that's >the case; but on the whole we'll merge as flagged.
>
> Questions *should not* be deleted if they are duplicates unless:
>
> - the question has a low number of views
> - A low number of votes
> - Really poor answers that don't merit staying around
>
> We want to keep valuable content, even if the questions are duplicates. So to sum up:
>
> If you hate duplication:
>
> - vote to close
> - Flag for merging if the question warrants merging (or has good content)
> - Vote to delete if the question meets the criteria I laid out above for deletion.

And all of this guidance stems from [this post by Jeff Atwood in 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/):

> Here are my official guidelines on question duplication:
>
> Having one “perfect” form of a question that contains every possible answer to every slight variation of that question is a myth at best and actively harmful at worst.
>
> Having dozens and dozens of variations of the same question is clearly bad. What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same duplicates to cover all possible search terms and common permutations of the question. It is also OK for these duplicates to have their own answers so people who find them don’t have to click yet again to get to a good answer.
>
> Let me be clear — too much question duplication is bad. Absolutely. You’ll get no argument whatsoever from me on that. But not enough question duplication is also bad. I know this does not sit well with programmers who love to think in binary black and white and cannot abide a single atom of duplicated content in the entire omniverse. But the honest, realistic answer to how much question duplication there should be is … “enough”. Question duplicates aren’t necessarily our enemy. They’re more like our, y’know, frenemies.
>
> So, as always, use your good judgment and please continue to close and merge duplicates as you see fit. However, bear in mind that cultivating and supporting a moderate amount of natural duplication actively helps the community. I wasn’t kidding when I said learn to stop worrying and love (some) duplication. Use the above guidelines and try to find a happy, reasonable medium somewhere in the middle there.

---

If you flag a closed question for merging, we'll take a look and see if it's merge material. If a duplicate with upvoted answers gets deleted, please raise a question on meta (I'm unclear if you can flag deleted questions; but if you can, please do that first before bringing up a question on meta).

For another moderator's perspective on this, [take this comment from Brad Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285758/why-was-this-question-deleted-when-answers-had-upvotes#comment153602_285759):

> Personally, I don't like to see the deletion of questions that have good answers. While the question it was closed as a duplicate of was a far better one, and had some even better answers, I don't know that it helps to delete this question and its answers. I'm becoming concerned with some of the deletions I've been seeing lately of duplicate questions, many of which had good answers. – Brad Larson♦ [Feb 10 '15 at 15:15](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285758/why-was-this-question-deleted-when-answers-had-upvotes#comment153602_285759)